# django efficient way to combine 2 queries or make a compound one?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

my (simplified) models are like this:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    wikiedit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    writers = models.ManyToManyField(User,null=True,blank=True)
class Writer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Now I am trying to build a queryset which includes all stories that meet: `wikiedit = True or user in writers`

So inside my view I make two queries:

```
wikistories = Story.objects.filter(wikiedit=True)
writerstories = request.user.objects.story_set.filter
```

But I would like to make this with just one database hit if it is possible. I guess it would be more efficient. I cannot find if the in operator is supported in this m2m relations in the sense:

```
 Story.objects.filter(writers__contains=request.user) #but this is a TypeError
```

Maybe is just more efficient to make 2 querysets and then join them in a list, but would love to have it in one.

Any clues? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check an M2M relation, you just do `=`, not `contains`:

```
Story.objects.filter(writers=request.user)
```

And you can use `Q` objects to do an `or` query:

```
Story.objects.filter(Q(wikiedit=True) | Q(writers=request.user))
```

Comment: great! it works, might be a too basic question but I did not manage to find this info for hours! Just a note for further readers, this might include repeated results, they might be excluded:
`Story.objects.filter( qwriters | (qwiki & ~qwriters))` where qwriters and qwiki are the corresponing Q objects. Thanks!